# Center Brand and links to left and right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to have the Brand centered and links to the left and right of it. In the example below I would like Brand to be between projects and resume. http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1432/

HTML:

```
    <a class="site-title" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/">{{ site.title }}</a>
<header class="site-header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="/blog">blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="/projects">projects</a></li>
          <li><a href="/resume">resume</a></li>
          <li><a href="/contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .navbar-nav{
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        float:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sound a litle bit bored but if you put your brand inside of li element before project li :)

```
<li><a href="/projects">projects</a></li>
<li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a></li>
<li><a href="/resume">resume</a></li>
```

Comment: That unfortunately adds Brand in the drop down menu when you collapse the window

Comment: where do you locate the brand when menu are collapse in small browsers?

Comment: dont really understand your question. The Brand will be in the navbar when the navbar is collapsed.

Comment: as it is a not an answer in a code form, but here is done exact as asked: [bootsnipp.com](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/navbar-brand-centered)